# How to specify the target directory for LibreOffice 4.0.2.2 .msi file?

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer, command-line, libreoffice

How can I specify the target directory for the LibreOffice 4.0.2.2 .msi installation?

The .msi file is here:
http://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/4.0.2.2/win/x86/LibreOffice_4.0.2.2_Win_x86.msi

The following script installs LibreOffice in C:\Program Files (x86):

```
msiexec.exe /qn /norestart /Lime .Npackd\InstallMSI.log /i ".Npackd\LibreOffice_4.0.2.2_Win_x86.msi" TARGETDIR="C:\Users\t\Downloads" ALLUSERS=1 MSIFASTINSTALL=7
```

Comment: Try passing the TARGETDIR option prior to the /i option; there may be some odd precedence behavior there. The .msi file may also be built in such a way that its target directory can't be overridden on the command line; in that case you'd need to unpack the .msi's contents, modify the target directory, and then repack the modified contents into a new .msi file.

Comment: ...also, if you're trying to do a user-specific install, why specify the ALLUSERS option?

Comment: C:\Users\t\Downloads is just for testing. It could be anything like F:\LibreOffice. The application should be installed for all users.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I test it on an XP VM. Let me know if you could make it work at least on one Windows version.

Comment: moving TARGETDIR before /i also does not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like LibreOffice wants to use INSTALLLOCATION instead of TARGETDIR, according to their [wiki](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Deployment_and_Migration).

Try this:
`msiexec.exe /qn /norestart /Lime .Npackd\InstallMSI.log /i ".Npackd\LibreOffice_4.0.2.2_Win_x86.msi" INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Users\t\Downloads" ALLUSERS=1 MSIFASTINSTALL=7`